# select all but few columns in impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

Is there a way to replicate the below in impala?

```
SET hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE MyTableParquet PARTITION (A='SumVal', B='SumOtherVal') SELECT `(A)?+.+` FROM MyTxtTable WHERE A='SumVal'
```

Basically I have a table in hive as text with 1000 fields, and I need a select that drops off the field A.  The above works for Hive but now impala, how can I do this in impala without specifying all other 999 fields directly?